# WPF ListView image depending on status column

Tags: wpf, image, listview

I'd like to show an icon instead of a value in a listview. Basically, the ListView is bind to  ModelView-Class (Observable-Collection as a property in that) and has a column called "status". Depending on status value, I'd like to show a different image. What would be the best way to do it. I read about DataTemplate, but I don't know where to hook in the code to switch the image.

MV-Class constructor looks like:

```
public TaskViewModel()
        {
            this.TaskCollection = ac.GetAllTasks();
        }
```

Many thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a DataTrigger. Here's an example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DisabledImageTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Active">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ActiveImageTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your images path/name dictated by code behind (this is bad but sometimes happens), you could implement `IValueConverter` and name it like `StatusToIconConverter`. See [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) with a simple example.

Regarding `Data Templates` See at the `DataTemplateSelector` class. [Here is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) also a very simple example.
The key point is to define simple class which just analizes a passed in value and returns an appropriate data template, obviously you have to declare one data template per image.

Comment: Yeah, but how hook it to my ViewModel-Class?

Comment: ViewModel should not be aware of View logic, so it just exposing Status. View in DataTempalteSelector switches an image depending on ViewModel Status (DataTemplateSelector should receive ViewModel instance as parameter in a method SelectTemplate(object item, ...)